# Getting NullReferenceException when using refresh token in IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, oauth, xamarin, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

When refreshing my token using the IdentityModel client library....

```
var result = _tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync (refreshToken).Result;
```

I'm getting a NullReferenceException. This doesn't happen every time after getting an AccessToken and RefreshToken but only after the tokens are hours old.  For example, I can get a AT and RT and consistently use the RT to get more AT and RT and it works fine.  Let the code sit for a few hours and try to use the RT again and it throws the error.  StackTrack is below.  I would think if it was some sort of simple expiration issue I would have got a more graceful isError=true in the TokenResponse object.

```
at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClientExtensions.Merge (IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient client, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 explicitValues, System.Object extra) [0x00016] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClientExtensions.RequestRefreshTokenAsync (IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient client, System.String refreshToken, System.Object extra, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SellMore.Functions.RefreshToken (System.String refreshToken) [0x0001d] in /Users/darrell/Mono Projects/SellMore/SellMoreApp/SellMore/SellMore/Classes/Functions.cs:41
```

Comment: Stupid issue, my _tokenClient variable was null

Answer (score 0):

Stupid issue, my _tokenClient variable was nul